# issues with remote:true in link_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm a bit at a loss here. I'm using `link_to` with `remote:true`, which correctly renders the `data-remote="true"` attribute in HTML. However, the request is not being made as an ajax request.

I've searched around a bit, and it seems as if the problem is javascript related. My `application.js` is as follows:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I have the route set up correctly, the correct method in the controller gets hit and executed, but then of course the corresponding html view cannot be found (because I want the request to be ajax and I hence only created the corresponding js view).

It's not the first time that I've come across this problem in my current project - I recently tried to used `method: :post` in a `link_to`, which I understand also uses javascript combined with a `data-method="post"` attribute, but again, things wouldn't work.

FWIW, I'm on Rails 4.1.1. Perhaps it's also worth noting that `remote:true` in forms works just as it should. It's only in the `link_to` that it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh - I solved my own problem.

The link is part of a `div` with the class `summary`. I wanted to make the `div` clickable, without messing with the links in the div, and added the following

```
$(".summary").click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr("data-href");
    return false;
  });

$(".summary a").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This works great for standard links, bit will of course interfere with the JS interactions that are required when using `remote:true` et al.

Comment: which makes it all the more annoying ;-)